# Android a git repo for each build flavors

Tags: android, git, android-build-flavors

I'm having a multi flavors android project, and one of my flavors is a version of the project that I want to share on github but not the others because they contains some customer related data, so I'm just wondering if I could somehow push only the code of the let's say public flavor to a different git repo which is the github repo, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create github private repositories ([see the pricing](https://github.com/pricing)), for your customer based products or create repositories in gitlab ([see the pricing](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/)). I suggest you for your customer related projects use gitlab which is free (depending on what you want check link above).

If you want in same project keep some part private [read this article](https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/)

Comment: the issue is how to push only the public code in the github repo and exclude the rest knowing that this code is in a separate build variant .

Comment: @Amine you should create different branches of project or dublicate your repo as private and public repositories

Comment: @Amine check my link article in answer